# one-to-many scalability and efficiency of getting the many - parse.com

Tags: database, parse-platform, one-to-many, scalability, parse-cloud-code

I have a question about the scalability of getting the many from a one-to-many relationship in parse.com. Below is a diagram of what I am trying to do.

[image]

I have a `Like` object that has a `userWhoLiked` and a `messageLiked` attributes as pointers. My question is in regards to checking if a `User` has liked a message already when loading a feed of `Message` objects. I was thinking that I could write some `cloud code` that would return both the `Message` itself as well as information about if the `User` has already liked that object. However, I feel like this would be very inefficient. I would in essence have a query for all the `Message` objects (which will be n objects long), and then another query for finding if the `User` has already liked that `Message` object by going through all the `Like` objects n times and checking the `userWhoLiked` and `messageLiked` based on the user logged in and `Message` I am checking. I am going to use the pointer to build the one-to-many relationship because the number of `Like` objects will be arbitrarily large. Is the method that I have described (using `cloud code` and then checking the `Like` objects ) for getting if a user has liked an object is okay and scalable? Is there a better way, or any suggestions? I appreciate your time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do one query on `Like` objects where the `userWhoLiked` key is equal to the current user? This will return all of the objects which the current user has liked and you can also infer that all objects not included have not been liked.

In case you haven't checked it out yet, I'd highly recommend [the Parse Anypic tutorial which has a very similar structure](https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic)

Comment: Thanks for the response, the link you included was helpful. I am going to do what you said and then also cache the results.